# How to configure 2 public IP?

Tags: networking, routes, ip, firewall

I need to configure one more public IP, I have a router cisco series 1800 and a router ASA. The ASA have this configuration:

```
interface Vlan1
nameif inside
security-level 100
ip address 192.168.116.1 255.255.255.0
!
interface Vlan2
nameif outside
security-level 0
ip address 200.91.162.154 255.255.255.248
!
```

But when I create a new VLAN the public ip overlaps with the existent...
How can I solve that problem?

Answer (score -1):

The ASA does not support secondary addressing...

I think you want to NAT a public ip on the same subnet as the vlan2 (outside) interface to get that 1800 router or something else online?

try this (assuming you do not have an asa 5505 restricted)

Recommendation: create a dmz for external hosts/servers/routers.

interface Vlan3
nameif dmz
security-level 50
ip address 172.16.10.1 255.255.255.0

interface ethernet0/4
switchport access vlan 3

object network obj-1800-rtr
 host 172.16.10.10

object network outside_host_200.91.162.155
 host 200.91.162.155

object network inside_host_obj-1800-rtr
 nat (dmz,outside) static outside_host_200.91.162.155

Assign 172.16.10.10 to the router's public interface and connect it to port 4 (or whatever port you assign) on the ASA to vlan3 (dmz).